# LinearLayoutManager prefetching not working

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, kotlin

I have a RecyclerView displaying variable height posts.
I calculate the height needed in "OnBindViewHolder" where the width is constant with the following code:

```
val videoLayoutParams: ViewGroup.LayoutParams = videoView.layoutParams
val height: Int =  (postWidth.toFloat() * scale).roundToInt()
videoLayoutParams.height = height
videoView.layoutParams = videoLayoutParams
```

The only other line I can think of takes a considerable time is a "Glide" load line.

The problem is: Scrolling is very jittery and laggy.

I logged "OnBindViewHolder" and found it's called exactly when the view first comes to the screen.

I've looked into prefetching, and supposedly it's implemented and enabled by default, I even tried enabling it explicitly. I've tried everything to make it work, but still "OnBindViewHolder" get called when the view first comes to the screen.

I'm using RecyclerView version 27.1.1

How should I go about this? When and where should I calculate the height, or better yet how do I bind 2 more views than visible(prefetch)?

Comment: What do you mean first view? Pre-fetching is binding views "below" while you scroll, it has no effect for first layout.

Comment: What I mean is it doesn't bind views below the current visible rectangle.
It only binds those visible not those about to be visible.